# C# - linq join select - operating on original selected objects

Tags: c#, linq, join

In my C# .NET application I have two objects: *Article*, which is some defined article with its overall price (meaning the price which should be calculated by multiplying the article's price by the quantity of articles ordered) and *ArticleOrdered* which contains quantity of articles ordered and that article's price.
I have the collections of both: collection of articles, which is the collection of ALL articles in the database and collection of only ordered articles.
What I now have to do is for each article which is ordered calculate it's overall price by multiplying single article's price by quantity ordered.
For that I decided to use *linq* statement, which selects the common part (using *join* of course) of both lists (all articles list and ordered articles list). The thing now is that I have to perform some actions (calculating the final price) on the original objects of type Article using fields from orderedArticles. Now I do everything that (very bad ;) ) way:

```
       var commonArticles = from art in articlesList
            join orderedArt in orderedArticlesList on art.Id equals orderedArt.Id
            select art;

        var commonOrderedArticles = from art in articlesList
            join orderedArt in orderedArticlesList on art.Id equals orderedArt.Id
            select orderedArt;

        foreach (var art in commonArticles)
        {
            foreach (var orderedArt in commonOrderedArticles)
            {
                if (art.Id == orderedArt.Id)
                {
                    art.Price += orderedArt.QuantityOrdered*orderedArt.Price;
                }
            }

        }
```

...because it gives me the ability to work on Articles' references.
The only difference between both *linq* statements is that in the first statement I select *art*, and in the second *orderedArt*.
How to make these two linq statements one and perform calculations on original Article's objects properly?  I thought about selecting some anonymous type using *new* keyword there, but as far as I know that will return the completely new type, so working on *art.Price* I would not work on the reference (original) object, but on the copy.
That is also why I now have to perform these strange foreach loops and check if corresponding Id's are the same.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `orderedArticlesList` does not contain multiple entries for an article (i.e. the same `Id` does not occur twice in the list), you can do:

```
var orderedArticalTotals =
    from ordered in orderedArticlesList 
    from article in articlesList
    where article.Id == ordered.Id
    select new {
        Article = article,
        OrderTotals = ordered.QuantityOrdered * ordered.Price
    }

foreach (var total in orderedArticalTotals) 
    total.Article.Price += total.OrderTotals;
```

If there could be multiple entries for the same article in the `orderedArticlesList`:

```
var orderedArticalTotals =
    from ordered in orderedArticlesList 
    group ordered by ordered.Id into g
    select new {
        Article = articlesList.Single(a => a.Id == g.Id),
        OrderTotals = g.Sum(o => o.QuantityOrdered * o.Price)
    }
```

And do the update in the same way:

```
foreach (var total in orderedArticalTotals) 
    total.Article.Price += total.OrderTotals;
```

Comment: Actually the list does not contain multiple elements with the same IDs, so the first way is totally fine. Thank you so much, that is exactly what I wanted ;). I didn't think of creating anonymous type with type references inside...